# Select Query and will appear to comboBox in Netbeans & mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I got problem on this code: 
 `String charitysql = "SELECT wardName, charityRoomID FROM tbl_charityward,tbl_charityroom2 
WHERE tbl_charityward.charityWardID = tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID";`

```
 try { 

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(charitysql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String wardname = rs.getString("wardName");
                cb_ward2.addItem(wardname);
                String roomid = rs.getString("charityRoomID");
                cb_room2.addItem(roomid);                    

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

this is my tables structure:
`tbl_charityward

charityWardID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

wardName varchar(20),

status varchar(20),

PRIMARY KEY (charityWardID)`

`tbl_charityRoom2

charityRoomID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

status varchar(20), 

charityWardID int,

PRIMARY KEY (charityRoomID, charityWardID),

FOREIGN KEY (charityWardID) REFERENCES tbl_charityward (charityWardID)`

this is my tables  with values:
`tbl_charityward

+-------------+----------+--------+

|charityWardID| wardName | status |

+-------------+----------+--------+

|......1......| Surgical |..Open..|

|......2......| .Obygine |..Open..|

|......3......| Pediatric|..Open..|

+-------------+----------+--------+`

tbl_charityroom2
+-------------+--------+-------------+
|charityRoomID| status |charityWardID|
+-------------+--------+-------------+
|......1......|..Open..|......1......|
|......2......|..Open..|......1......|
|......3......|..Open..|......2......|
+-------------+--------+-------------+

I have 2 comboBox:
`cb_ward2 = which contains wardName`

`cb_room2 = which contains CharityRoomID`

If I select a wardName from `cb_ward2`, then the `cb_room2` will show the corresponding charityRoomID.

example:
I select `Surgical` and the `charityRoomID = 1, 2` will appear on `cb_room2`,
and when i select `Obygine`, the `charityRoomID = 3` will only appear on `cb_room2`,
but when i select `Pediatric`, no `charityRoomID will appear on cb_room2`

I am using **Netbeans** and **MYSQL**

---

**EDIT :**

```
import java.sql.*;<br>
import javax.swing.*;<br>
public class addBed extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form addBed
     */
    public addBed() {
        initComponents();
    }

    void loadcombo() {


            try {


            String charitysql = "SELECT wardName, charityRoomID FROM tbl_charityward, tbl_charityroom2 WHERE tbl_charityward.charityWardID = ?";  
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(charitysql);
            pst.setInt(1,tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {

                    cb_ward2.addItem(rs.getString(1));

                    cb_room2.addItem(rs.getString(2));                    

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }




    }
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
       conn = myconn.ConnectDb();
       loadcombo();
    }                                 

    private void btn_add2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using is not the proper way of using PreparedStatement

Do like this

```
String charitysql = "SELECT wardName, charityRoomID FROM tbl_charityward,tbl_charityroom2 
WHERE tbl_charityward.charityWardID = ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(charitysql);
pst.setInt(1,tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: @Jugadu Thanks for rectifying the mistake

Answer (score 0):

As your basic requirement is to show data into two `ComboBoxes`, you can do it as:

You can use a `loadcombo()` to load your `cb_ward2` combobox with database values.

```
void loadcombo() {
    try
    {
     Connection conn=null;
 PreparedStatement pst=null;
 ResultSet rs=null;
// Your database connections 

     String charitysql = "SELECT wardName FROM tbl_charityward";
     pst = conn.prepareStatement(charitysql);
     rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){                            
        cb_ward2.addItem(rs.getString(1));
    }
    con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error"+e);
    }    
}
```

Now you can use `ActionListener` on `cb_ward2` as:

```
cb_ward2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        try
    {
        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement pst=null,pst1=null;
        ResultSet rs=null,rs1=null;
    //your database connection
                Object name=cb_ward2.getSelectedItem();
                    pst=con.preparedStatement("select charityWardID from tbl_charityward where wardName=?");
                pst.setObject(1,name);
                    rs= pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
                      pst1=con.preparedStatement("select charityRoomID from tbl_charityroom2 where charityWardID=?");
                      pst1.setInt(1,rs.getInt(1));
                      rs1=pst1.executeQuery();
                      while(rs1.next()){
                      cb_room2.addItem(rs1.getInt(1));
                      }
            }
                con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("GG"+e);
    }

    }


    });
```

Comment: i tried your code but error appears: 'Uncompiled Source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>' and i have noticed in 'pst.setString(1,**tbl_charityroom2**.charityWardID)' 'tbl_charityroom2' got red underline. My bad in putting tbl_charityroom instead of tbl_charityroom2.

Comment: What is your table name tbl_charityroom or tbl_charityroom2?

Comment: `pst.setString(1,tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID)` should be `pst.setInt(1,tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID)` because `charityWardID` is `int` see the edit

Comment: nothing happens. same as pst.setString, got red underline

Comment: what do you mean by declaring it? im sorry im new in netbeans

Comment: just add your code at last of your question I'll see it and stack trace too.

Comment: just try this `String charitysql = "SELECT wardName, charityRoomID FROM tbl_charityward,tbl_charityroom2
WHERE tbl_charityward.charityWardID = tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID";` and remove this  `pst.setInt(1,tbl_charityroom2.charityWardID);` because you can  not directly get the value

Comment: the code you gave is same as the code i posted above. With that code the wardName appears in cb_ward2 but it duplicates the value. on wardName the values are Surgical, Obygine, Pediatric. Surgical have 2 charityRoomID (1,2), Obygine (1) and Pediatric (0) but when i click the cb_ward2 there are 3 items/value appear (Surgical,Surgical,Obygine) as you can see, it duplicates the Surgical. I want to remove the duplicate but i do not know the right code should i put. And when i select Surgical there are 3 items/values appear on cb_room2 (1,2,3) and that should be (1,2) only.

Comment: Hi. same result, duplicates again

Comment: See the edit. I am not sure about this but try it once.

Answer (score 0):

try using an arrayList !! it will give you a push like effect

something like this

```
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("\ntrying connection");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/products?user=root&password=");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT categorie FROM product");
        while (rs.next()) {
            categories.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        for (String item : categories) {
            ComboBoxCategorie.addItem(item);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            } // ignore
            stmt = null;
        }
    }
```

you can ignore the catch and finally clause!! just close the stmt